# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n |f(\frac{j}{n}) - f(\frac{j-1}{n})|^{3/2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose $f(x)=x^3$.

How to evalueate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n |f(\frac{j}{n}) - f(\frac{j-1}{n})|^{3/2}$?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n |f(\frac{i}{n}) - f(\frac{i-1}{n})|^{3/2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n |(\frac{j}{n})^3 - (\frac{j-1}{n})^3|^{3/2}$$

I tried $x = j/n$, so $$\left|(\frac{j}{n})^3 - (\frac{j-1}{n})^3\right|^{3/2} = (x^3-(x-\frac{1}{n})^3)^{3/2}$$

Then, I think I might need to use the integral: $$\int_0^1 (x^3-(x-\frac{1}{n})^3)^{3/2} dx$$

Am I right? I do not know how to calculate this integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $0$. Here is general result. Suppose $f$ is a function which satisfies the inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|$ for some finite constant $C$. [ Any function with a bounded derivative satisfies this; $x^{3}$ certainly does this on $[0,1]$]

Then $\sum_{j=1}^n |f(\frac{j}{n}) - f(\frac{j-1}{n})|^{3/2}
\le C^{3/2}n(\frac 1 {n^{3/2}})\to 0$.

Comment: Is there a name for this result? Where can I read a proof of it?

Comment: If you are asking why $x^{3}$ satisfies such an inequality, it is simple: $|x^{3}-y^{3}|=|(x-y)(x^{2}+xy+y^{2})\leq |x-y|(1+1+1)=3|x-y|$ for $0\le x,y \le 1$. @user546106

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean the general result is that if a function $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition, then $\sum_{j=1}^n |f(\frac{j}{n}) - f(\frac{j-1}{n})|^{3/2}
\le C^{3/2}n(\frac 1 {n^{3/2}})\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$? You explained why $f(x) = x^3$ is Lipschitz, but how to prove the general result?

Comment: General result for a Lipschitz function is exactly what I proved. @user546106